# facebook 'invite friends' get successful answer but not notification (swift)

Tags: facebook, swift2, facebook-invite-friends

I need some help with the 'invite friends' functionality of facebook.

The code I am using to invite friends is:

```
let inviteDialog:FBSDKAppInviteDialog = FBSDKAppInviteDialog()
if(inviteDialog.canShow()){
    let appLinkUrl:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://fb.me/9999999999")!
    let previewImageUrl:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/myimage.png")!

    let inviteContent:FBSDKAppInviteContent = FBSDKAppInviteContent(appLinkURL: appLinkUrl)
    inviteContent.previewImageURL = previewImageUrl

    inviteDialog.content = inviteContent
    inviteDialog.delegate = self
    inviteDialog.show()
}
```

When I do the test in my iPhone, It redirect me to the facebook app and list my friends, then I choose some of then, send the invitation and get the following result in the logs.

```
[didComplete: 1]
```

**But my friends does not get the notification.**

I am the administrator in the facebook console, one of the invite friends is in the developer role and the other one is in the tester role.

I created the appLink with facebook.

The configuration in my facebook console is:[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Are these other users using an iOS device as well? Invites will only be shown on platforms that you have set up for your app.

Comment: Yes all of us are using iOS devices but only I have the app installed. I read that only users that do not have the app installed receive the notification, try this and not working. Also that in the Facebook console you need to enter a valid app id. Not the app is that is in testing, instead one that is in production (app store). In other posts I read that you will only be able to test once your app is in the app store.

Comment: If you mean push notifications, then it is not guaranteed that the invite will be surfaced as a push notification. You can check if the recipients are correctly getting the app invites by going to More > Apps > App Invites in  the recipient's Facebook app.

Comment: Bangdel, your are right. I just saw the invite in that section. I supposed the notification doesn't appear because is a test app. Maybe in production, the notification will arrive. Can you put it as  an aswerd so I can mark that. Thanks!